# Should an SQL Union or Join be used?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I'm trying to get the zip codes and the # of calls for that zip code for 2 tables I have, patients and physicians. I'm getting the #of calls by counting the zip code, like if there are 5 patients with zip code 79555 then the count would be 5. If patients table has 3 people with that zip and physicians table has 4, it should return the zip code and 7. I tried the union below. At first glance it looks like it does what I want, but I want duplicate zip codes to be summed up, can I use the sum function in a union? Or do I have to create a join?

```
SELECT zip_code, COUNT(zip_code) AS Num_Patient_Calls FROM patients GROUP BY zip_code
UNION ALL
SELECT zip_code, COUNT(zip_code) AS Num_Physician_Calls FROM physicians GROUP BY zip_code
```

**EDIT: Solution**
I used the responses from Gordon and dweiss to produce this SQL code. It does what I want, which is take two fields from unrelated tables which may or may not have the same value, count the number of records which have that value in each of the tables, then sum the results from both tables. Example: 6 instances of the zip code 99709 in patients table, 1 in physicians table, value displayed is 99709 - 7.

```
SELECT zip_code, SUM(Patient_Calls) FROM (
    SELECT zip_code, COUNT(zip_code) AS Patient_Calls FROM patients GROUP BY zip_code
    UNION ALL
    SELECT zip_code, COUNT(zip_code) AS Physician_Calls FROM physicians GROUP BY zip_code
) AS new_table
GROUP BY zip_code ORDER BY `new_table`.`zip_code`
```

Comment: Glad you got to the solution!  I changed my answer slightly and it should also work.  It's a tad different from your solution, but I still a good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As these are unrelated tables, you want to use a `UNION`.  Also, `COUNT` and `SUM` are different functions, and in this case you're looking for `COUNT`.  SUM will add all the values up whereas `COUNT` will give you the number of times the row is found in a `GROUP`.
How about something like this?

```
SELECT zip_code,COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT zip_code AS Num_Patient_Calls FROM patients
UNION ALL
SELECT zip_code AS Num_Physician_Calls FROM physicians
) AS new_table
GROUP BY zip_code
```

Comment: @dweiss, care to expand the answer with an example of a SUM over the union sub select?

Comment: @astander you got me just as I was typing it up :).  I also went ahead and explained why you want COUNT and not SUM.

Comment: This should do what I want. Let me be sure I understand it though. It's acting on the union as though it were it's own table? And basically doing what I did with the individual selects, but for the data in both tables because of the union? Is there a good tutorial on more advanced SQL stuff like this?

Comment: Thats nice. Maybe specify that if you wish, you can use either a DISTINCT instead of the group by in the sub select or a COUNT/GROUP BY in the sub select and then a SUM in the outer select. Also try to hilight the differnce between UNION and UNION ALL

Comment: Have a look at the following links http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/ and http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/

Comment: I think it worked! Initially got the error thing #1054 - but removed the "As num_patient_calls" and the one for physicians and it ran correctly. Thanks!

Comment: @dweiss Actually, didn't quite do what I wanted. It returns a count on the number of zip codes. If both the patients, and physicians table have the zip code 76555 it will return two. If patients has 3 people with that zip and physicians has 4, it should return the zip code and 7. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, Jonathan, you're right!  The zip_code should not be grouped in the subqueries as I was doing.  I've updated this in my code.  I haven't tried it, but go ahead and try it and let me know if it solves the new issue.

Comment: @Jonathan Great!  I hadn't actually tried it but I suspected it'd get you what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question, you need either a `UNION ALL` or `FULL OUTER JOIN`, because you may have zip codes with only one type of call.

I would structure the results as such:

```
select zip_code, sum(Patient_Call) as Num_Patient_Calls,
       sum(Physician_Call) as Num_Physician_Calls,
       sum(Patient_Call + Physician_Call) as Num_Calls
from 
(
  (SELECT zip_code, 1 AS Patient_Call, 0 as Physician_Call
   FROM patients
  )
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT zip_code, 0 AS Patient_Call, 1 as Physician_Call
   FROM physicians
  )
) calls
GROUP BY zip_code
```

If you are running this query multiple times, you can experiment with aggregating within each subquery, to see if that is faster (for instance, if there is an index on zip_code, then it may be faster).

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! I didn't use your exact response, but your response did lead me to the correct answer to do what I wanted!